# Why do black artifacts appear on exported model?

Tags: export, artifacts, obj

Why do black artifacts appear on the faces of my model When I export it to .obj format? I use Blender 3.2.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume the black lines appear in places where your model has some edges. Seems like the normals are causing some weird shading.

Try going into edit mode, hitting <kbd>A</kbd> to select everything, and then hitting <kbd>Shift + N</kbd> to recalculate normals.

Alternatively, you might also have some geometry right under the surface of that top layer, and they start clipping through a little, in which case you should either remove or lower that geometry.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the sugestions, I try but it doesn't work to me, after so many tryes to fix this I reach the conclusion of maybe I doing wrong something about the export and that is, in the menu of exporting I check the box of intersect faces and finally I get solved...[image]